# Bean Validation API needed, when using Hibernate Validator Engine?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, bean-validation, nhibernate-validator

In my Java EE 7 OpenShift project I'm using javaee-api version 7.0. For my model I added the depency validation-api version 1.1.0, but that wasn't enough. Then I tried with

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and this works.
Is the validation-api implicit in this depency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Bean Validation and Hibernate Validator

The [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) is the reference implementation of the [Bean Validation 1.1](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/) specification.

Check the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/), for example, and you'll realize the [`hibernate-validator`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final) artifact *does include* the [`validation-api`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api) artifact as a dependency.

### Bean Validation and Java EE 7 API

The Bean Validation is defined in the `javax.validation` package and sub-packages.

The Java EE 7 is an [umbrella specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html) and, among other specifications, it includes the Bean Validation 1.1 specification.

It means the [`javaee-api`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0) artifact includes the `javax.validation` package and sub-packages. However, no implementation for the Bean Validation is provided as dependency of that artifact.

In the other hand, some containers, such as WildFly and GlassFish, provide the Hibernate Validator dependency (or any other Bean Validation implementation) to be compliant with the Java EE 7 specification. In this situation, if you want to use something *specific* from the Hibernate Validator (that is, something from the `org.hibernate.validator` package or sub-packages), you need to add the [`hibernate-validator`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final) dependency with the `provided` scope.

Otherwise, if you won't use anything specific from the Hibernate Validator, the  [`javaee-api`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0) dependency should be just fine.